# d3js v5 circle packing with asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, promise

I am trying to replicate [the zoomable circle packing example on Observable](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-circle-packing), but in an HTML page with my own data. First, I'm trying to replicate it with the flare sample json.

I'm having trouble working with the Promise data types. I can't get the chain of operations that converts the json into a d3.hierarchy object to resolve - the console always shows those objects as Pending and when it comes time to iterate across the children of the `focus` object, I get the error saying "`focus.descendants` is not a function."

I have read a few descriptions of how Promises work in version 5 of d3, but it's still not clear to me why my `.then()` statements are failing to resolve the Promises in time to apply the `descendants()` function to `focus`.

JSFiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/24ncLawv/2/

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's best to wrap you work inside the the `d3.json` callback (`then'): https://jsfiddle.net/z18sm5dn/

Comment: also your example is missing some functions such as zoom()

Comment: @RyanMorton Unless someone answers with an alternative, I'm going to convert your comment into the full answer.